# How can I fix a Nikon D7000 where the mode dial selects the wrong thing?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, camera-controls

On my Nikon D7000, the Exposure Mode Dial suddenly changed its alignment. When I select P, the camera chooses A. The setting indicated on the selector dial does not match the setting as shown in the screen. What shall I do?

Comment: How old is the camera? Did you try talking with Nikon (if in USA, [Customer support](https://support.nikonusa.com/app/contact)) about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If the offset is constant, you may need to take the dial off and put it back on again.  It may just pull off, or you may have to prise/peal off a cap and undo a screw.

By a constant offset I mean that a on dial with 4 positions A-D, selecting A would give mode B, B woudl give C... D gives A (or similar)

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point you could try installing the latest "firmware" for your camera. It's a fairly easy process...just thinking that yours may have somehow become corrupted?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this is likely to be the issue?

Comment: No...only that it's the most obvious place to start. You really ought to be using the latest releases of firmware anyway....Nikon release them to fix bugs which you may or may not have ever come across. There was an issue with "hot pixels" on the 7000 fixed with a release of upgraded firmware. It does no harm to be running the latest releases anyway ...and it takes less than five minutes to accomplish...so it's worth a shot!

Comment: Something else just occurred to me. What lens are you using? This could happen if the aperture setting has been moved off its minimum aperture.

Comment: Installing new (or the same) firmware will do absolutely nothing if it's a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a "reset?" (Hold both buttons with the green dot at the same time)...on the d7000 I think it's "qual" and the exposure compensation buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are good you'll have to send it in for repair, but you can try using a bulb blower to blast the knob, to make sure that it isn't just some loose random dirt up under the dial keeping the contacts from making contact.  You can also   press down the dial while making a full turn to see if you can knock the dirt out.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Chris's answer.

If it looks like the setting is always the same amount off like described by Chris H it's likely that the knob got shifted on the actual switch inside. Imagine taking a clock and rotating all the numbers a couple places. When the clock is at position 12 it shows 2, when at position 1 it shows 3 and so on.

**Safe Option**
Send it in for repairs to Nikon

**Less Risky Option** - *insert try at your own risk blurb*
If you can take the knob off you should be able to just shift it back into the correct position. You might be able to pull it off or pop it off with a screw driver or something.

**Risky Option**
If you don't want to take it off you could see if it's able to be shifted back into position, as it must have been shifted out of position without being removed, by trying to turn it without actually changing any settings. What I mean is try maybe pulling up on the knob while rotating it. This could disconnect it from the internal switch and you might be able to rotate it back into place. If the knob can only be turned so far in one direction try to over rotate it back into position.

Now these are all probably bad ideas but if you're desperate you can give those a shot but try at your own risk.